# Struggling with Codecademy HTML lesson

Tags: html, paragraphs

I need help in identifying the problem with my Codecademy html. I can't move forward because I can't seem to figure out what's really wrong.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>This is my first paragraph</p>
    <p>This is my second paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's what is brought to my attention for correcting my "error":

> Oops, try again. Make sure you write something between each set of `<p></p>` tags!

Comment: It may be better to raise issues / questions directly with Codecademy as they understand the context of what is trying to be established by the tutorial.

Comment: Where are you inputting this code?

Comment: I've managed to sort out the issue. It turns out the error was on Codecademy's system's side. I had to reset the code and re-type it so that the system could read as the correct. As I am new to web studies, programming syntax and this platform, I appreciate the way you were all responsive to my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the document type with `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your code, and then you need an opening `<html>` tage, without it, the browser just reads it as jibberish.

Correct code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <p>This is my first paragraph</p>
   <p>This is my second paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```